# Custom file doesn't work when directory is changed

Tags: python, interpreter

Okay, so I have this interpreter thing that I made out of boredom, but it doesn't work when I change its directory. When I have it in the same folder as the `main.py` file, it works fine, but when I put it in the `test` folder, I get an error.
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'individual' referenced before assignment`
This is what handles the argument for the file path:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    argv = sys.argv
    #try:
    if argv[1] != None:
        if argv[1].split("/"):
            target = argv[1].split("/")[len(argv[1].split("/"))-1]
            __main__(target)
        else:
            target = argv[1]
            __main__(target)
    else:
        print("No file specified")
    #except Exception as e:
        #print(e)
```

This is the main function that reads the file then interprets it:

```
def __main__(target):
    for file in os.listdir("."):
        if file.endswith(EXTEN):
            with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                for each in lines:
                    individual = each.split()
                
    process_command(individual)
```

I've already tried searching for what it means, and it's kind of helped me, so I figured this was my last hope.

Answer (score 0):

The error means you're referring to `individual` before you assign to it. Since the assignment to `individual` is buried under a few control flow statements, it's possible for you to get to `process_command(individual)` without going into the loop or reading the file.

Add `individual = []` (or `None` or some other default) at the top of your function to ensure that the variable exists regardless of the value of target or the contents of the file.

Comment: I've done that, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the new state of `__main__`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant block:

```py
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                for each in lines:
                    individual = each.split()
```

This code block is Never reached because `file.endswith(EXTEN)` is never true, or the `os.listdir(".") itself is empty. Also, any file that does reach this block but is empty would also not assign anything to individual. I recommend using a debugger or some print statements to see what files you're iterating through in your main function.

Comment: It should be true, because `EXTEN` is the same as the extension that I have it as in the `test` folder.

Comment: Like I said, I recommend going through this with a debugger to confirm what is happening. I can't diagnose further without knowing what your file system looks like.

Comment: The main.py file and the test folder are at the same level in the root folder, and the test.plux (custom extension) file is in the test folder.